# Is a KKT point a local optimum for strictly convex objective functions and non-convex constraints?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Consider the problem
\begin{equation}
\min_x f(x)~~~{\rm s.t.}~~~ g_i(x)\leq 0,~~i=1,\dots,I,
\end{equation}

where $x$ is the optimization parameter vector, $f(x)$ is the objective function and $g_i(x)$ is the $i$th constraint function. $I$ denotes the number of constraints.

Consider now a point $x^\star$ that satisfies the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions. In general, in non-convex optimization, a KKT point can be everything, i.e., a local optimum, a global optimum, a saddle point or even a maximum.

Can we claim that $x^\star$ is at least a local optimum
if we assume that $f(x)$ is a strictly convex function and that $g_i(x)$ are non-convex functions? All functions are at least twice continuously differentiable.

I have read this claim in this paper: http://kang.nt.e-technik.tu-darmstadt.de/nt/fileadmin/nas/Publications/2012/Cheng_TSP_2012_Posted.pdf [Appendix C] but I'm not 100% sure if this is true. I also could not find any literature about it.

Comment: In the paper, do the authors give any proof or references? Can you tell me  the name of the paper?

Comment: I have added a reference to the post.

Comment: Did you see the reference [14] within?

Comment: Do you mean [24]? Yes I did that but I could not really verify the result.

Comment: I was looking for a counter example but gerw did that nicely. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the following problem:
\begin{align*}
 \min \quad & x_1^2 + \frac12 x_2^2, \\
 \text{such that} \quad & -x_1^2 - x_2^2 \le -1.
\end{align*}
The objective is strictly convex, but the constraint is strictly concave.

It is easy to check that $x = (0,1)$ is the global minimizer, and it should also be the only local minimizer.
The point $x = (1,0)$ is, however, a KKT point with multiplier $\mu = 1$.
But it is not a local minimizer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Some times is easier to find a counter example than proving sth that is not right ;-).

Answer (score 0):

If your point $x^*$ is at least a local minimum, then the KKT conditions are satisfied for some KKT multipliers if the local minimum, $x^*$, satisfies some regulatory conditions called constraint qualifications. E.g. if the constraint gradients be linearly independence (the LICQ condition).

There are many constraint qualifications, and some may apply to your constraints.

Comment: You are right in every word but I am assuming that $x^\star$ is a KKT point, not a local optimum. My question is: Is a KKT pointer under the formulated conditions also a local optimum?

Comment: Oh, ok. In the general case this is not so, because the KKT conditions are necessary, but not sufficient. For the KKT conditions to be sufficient, the constraints must also be smooth and convex. It may still be so for your functions, though.

Answer (score 0):

Besides satisfying the KKT condition, SOSC is also required.
Reference: Theorem 1 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0898.pdf

Comment: Please make an effort to give Readers a fuller explanation of what "SOSC" means in this context.  Quoting or paraphrasing (in complete sentences) the most relevant part of a referenced (linked) explanation (with proper credit) is apprpriate.